# VBA to open Excel Workbook if file exists, and open a different if it does not

Tags: excel, vba

I have spent my whole morning on this and cannot get it working properly.  A simple Excel userform was created asking for a filename.  If the file exists in the directory I want it to open.  If it does not exist I want a "template" file opened instead.  I have the does not exist working properly, however cannot get the "does exist" part working. Please help.

```
Private Sub CmdEnter_Click()
Dim Path As String
Dim File As String
 
Path = Range("Search!B1")
File = TxtOrder.Value
    
'If File exists then open.
If Dir(Path & File & ".xlsm") = Path & File & ".xlsm" Then
    Workbooks.Open FileName:=Path & File & ".xlsm"
    
'If File does not exist then open.
ElseIf Dir(Path & File & ".xlsm") = Error Then
    Workbooks.Open FileName:=Path & "QCSFormTrial.xlsm"
    
End If

'Close Dialog and Close Workbook
Workbooks("QCSLaunch.XLSM").Close SaveChanges:=False
```

End Sub

Comment: What string does `Path` contain? If it contains a string ending in "\", you should use `If Dir(Path & File & ".xlsm") <> "" Then`. Instead of `ElseIf Dir(Path & File & ".xlsm") = Error Then` use just `Else`.

Comment: It does end in "\"  Right now this is just trying to get a workable version so I made that cell editable so it could be changed easily.

Comment: Then try implementing what I recommended. Anyhow `Dir(Path & File & ".xlsm") = Error` does not have any meaning in VBA. `Dir()` returns a path or an empty string. Never a error and even if it should do so, that way of checking for error does not exist in VBA.

Comment: In the meantime, I posted an answer. It will set a workbook (`wb`) which can be any of the two. Your code will raise an error if the first condition is `True`...

Comment: How is `"QCSLaunch.XLSM"` related to the code? Is it the workbook containing the cell with the path? Is it the workbook containing this code? Why are you closing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try this way:

```
Private Sub CmdEnter_Click()
 Dim Path As String, File As String, wb As Workbook
 
 Path = Range("Search!B1")
 File = TxtOrder.value
    
 'If File exists then open.
 If dir(Path & File & ".xlsm") <> "" Then
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Path & File & ".xlsm")
 Else 'else, open the other one:
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Path & "QCSFormTrial.xlsm")
 End If

 Stop 'check if the workbook has been open and press F5 to let code finishing
 wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `Dir(Path & File & ".xlsm") = Path & File & ".xlsm"` is basically saying does the folder path *I* named equal the folder path *I* named. The path isn't actually directed at the actual folder in way that will open it.

Try this: https://exceloffthegrid.com/vba-code-loop-files-folder-sub-folders/

```
Sub LoopAllFilesInAFolder()

'Loop through all files in a folder
Dim fileName As Variant
fileName = Dir("C:\Users\marks\Documents\")

While fileName <> ""
    
    'Insert the actions to be performed on each file
    'This example will print the file name to the immediate window
    Debug.Print fileName

    'Set the fileName to the next file
    fileName = Dir
Wend

End Sub
```

Or, you can remove the `If Then` and directly open the file. If the file exists, it will open, if not, it will `error`. You can use `error handling` then  continue.